# Eventbridge non-matched events

Tags: aws-event-bridge

As I understand all unmatched events in Amazon EventBridge will be discarded. So how can we count them to make sure that my events are not lost and all matched/routed to targets

For example if producer changes schema and it stops matching rule pattern as a result - how can I setup some sort of alarm of DLQ for such events?

Kind of "if rule1, if rule2, else ALL UNMATCHED to some queue"